# Slow SQL Queries, Order Table by Date?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a Sql-Server-2008 database that I am querying from on the regular that was over 30 million entries (joy!).  Unfortunately this database cannot be drastically changed because it is still in use for R/D.

When I query from this database, it takes FOREVER.  By that I mean I haven't been patient enough to wait for results (after 2 mins I have to cancel to avoid locking the R/D department out).  Even if I use a short date range (more than a few months), it is basically impossible to get any results from it.  I am querying with requirements from 4 of the columns and unfortunately have to use an inner-join for another table (which I've been told is very costly in terms of query efficiency -- but it unavoidable).  This inner joined table has less than 100k entries.

What I was wondering, is it is possible to organize the table to have it defaultly be ordered by date to reduce the number of results it has to search through?

If this is not possible, is there anything I can do to reduce query times?  Is there any other useful information that could assist me in coming up with a solution?

I have included a sample of the query that I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.TestName 
FROM [DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsUut] U 
INNER JOIN [DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsNumeric] N 
ON N.ModeDescription = 'Mode 8: Low Gain - Green-Blue' 
AND N.ResultsUutId = U.ResultsUutId
WHERE U.DeviceName = 'BO-32-3HK60-00-R' 
AND U.StartDateTime > '2011-11-25 01:10:10.001'
ORDER BY N.TestName
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You need an explain plan, or at least let us know what fields are indexed.

Comment: Do you have an index or anything on the field that you are ordering by, that includes TestName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like datetime may be a text based field and subsequently an index isn't being used?

Could you try the following to see if you have any speed improvement:

```
select distinct N.TestName 
from            [DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsUut] U 
inner join      [DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsNumeric] N 
    on N.ModeDescription = 'Mode 8: Low Gain - Green-Blue' 
    and N.ResultsUutId = U.ResultsUutId
where           U.DeviceName = 'BO-32-3HK60-00-R' 
                and U.StartDateTime > cast('2011-11-25 01:10:10.001' as datetime)
order by        N.TestName
```

It would also be worth trying changing your inner join to a left outer join as those occasionally perform faster for no conceivable reason (at least one that I'm not aware of).

Comment: Casting the date seems to improve the hit and miss-..ness of the query.  This is good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can add an index based on your date column, which should improve your query time. You can either use an alter table command, or use the table designer.

Is the sole purpose of the join to provide sorting? If so, a quick thing to try would be to remove this, and see how much of a difference it makes - at least then you'll know where to focus your attention.

Finally, SQL server management studio has some useful tools such as execution plans that can help diagnose performance issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems which may be causing delays in the execution of your query.

Indexes (except the primary key) do not reorder the data, they merely create an index (think phonebook) which orders a number of values and points back to the primary key.

Without seeing the type of data or the existing indexes, it's difficult, but at the very least, the following ASCENDING indexes might help:

[DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsNumeric] ModeDescription and ResultsUutId and TestName

[DalsaTE].[dbo].[ResultsUut] StartDateTime and DeviceName and ResultsUutId

Without the indexes above, the sample query you gave can be completed without performing a single lookup on the actual table data.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I have added the indexes to the Uut Table, but unfortunately I can't seem to add any indexes to the Numeric Table due to timeouts.  Any idea how to adjust that? (indexing 30million records takes a while I imagine)  Under Options the Execution time-out seems to be unlimited.